# How to show .psd image in phoneGap application?

Tags: cordova

I need How to show splash image using HTML which lasts 3 to 4 seconds and hide automatically. Give me code

Comment: stack over flow is not for giving u a code.....this is not a way to ask any question...& i think  your question's title doesn't match ur question....

Answer (score 1):

put this line at heading  part of your html

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=newfile.html">`

content=3; is a number of secound for displying ur splash screen

& URL=newfile.html is a html in which after splash screen ur application redirects...

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to AamirKhan's approach both iOS and Android have a native way for showing a splash screen:

For Android, add/change the following lines in your Activity class:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 3000); // for 3 seconds
```

For iOS you have to modify the .plist first and then disable the splash in your Javascript code. Details are described here: http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/ios-phonegap-splash-screen-control/